# 2 loops in archive.php (one for each category)

Tags: categories, loop, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type set up for a news blog on a site I'm building, the custom post type being `blog` consisting of 2 categories, `blog-image-post` ID=`3` and `blog-text-post` ID=`4`. I want to loop each category separately as each one is displayed and styled slightly differently in the archive. I currently have this:

```
    <div id="blog-grid">


<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

        <div class="blog-grid">
            <img class="blog-image" src="url-here" width="100" height="100" />
        </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>   

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>     

        <div class="blog-grid-text">
            <div class="blog-grid-text-wrap">
                <?php the_title(); ?> etc etc
            </div>
        </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div>
```

The first loop would be for `blog-image-post` ID=`3` and the second loop for `blog-test-post` ID=`4`, I'm not sure if this is at all possible? Can't figure it out, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switch conditionally. The `rewind_posts()` function allows you to loop through the same loop a second time, while the `has_term()` function allows you to check if the currently looped post has a specific term of a specific taxonomy.

```
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while ( have_posts() )
    {
        the_post();

        if ( ! has_term( 'term_A_slug/term_A_id', 'taxonomy' ) )
            continue;

        // display post here
    }
}
rewind_posts();

// Second loop
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while ( have_posts() )
    {
        the_post();

        if ( ! has_term( 'term_B_slug/term_B_id', 'taxonomy' ) )
            continue;

        // display post here
    }
}
```

Comment: First, jsFiddle is not for PHP :) Second, you need to use the `taxonomy_name`, not just `taxonomy` as second argument for `has_term()` ... hint: Look the function up in Codex for more in depth insights ;)

Comment: yep, I was only using jsFiddle to show the code, too long for a comment :) FYI it's fixed and works great, thanks for that, appreciated!